# Real-time Updates Facebook

Tags: c#, facebook-graph-api

Link:- [https://graph.facebook.com//subscriptions?access_token=APPToken](https://graph.facebook.com/%3CMyAppID%3E/subscriptions?access_token=APPToken)
passing parameter like this in Json format...

```
Data:- {
    "object": "user",
    "fields": "name, picture, friends, feed",
    "callback_url": "MyURL",
    "verify_token": "Passing AppToken"
       }
```

while calling this above URL, with Type **Post** but I am getting error message says that "**400 Bad Request**"

Please Help me on this issue...

Thanks,

Comment: We're going to need more information and likely some code to see what you're doing.

Comment: This is my FB subscription link,   https://graph.facebook.com/ AppID/subscriptions?access_token=AppAccessToken.  with api.. I am passing parameter  for  objects, fields, callback_url, verify_token, active. The data is passed in JSON format to the link. But it throws an error 400 bad request. I am using C# and calling this url from HTTPWebRequest....

Comment: https://graph.facebook.com/AppID/subscriptions?access_token=MyAppToken

Method Type Is "Post"


{
    "access_token": AccessToken,
    "objects": "user",
    "fields": "name,picture,friends",
    "callback_url": "http://dev.teamapi.pureprofile.com/socialnetwork/TestingFB?APIKEY=MyKey&FBToken=AccessToken",
    "verify_token": "161722060523727|ewJfuv9BxieM8ngq2Gy3uuy8W-A",
    "active": true
}


It throws an Error  
"400 Bad Request"


Plz help....

Comment: Try the same thing on the Graph API Explorer tool () and see if it gives the same error or not. http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer  Let us know how that goes.

Comment: This issue is resolve guys, thanks for support... I just follow the step which are mentioned in facebook real time updates, in the url i m just passing "method=post".

Answer (score 0):

Parameters should be in the url, not the body.  See http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/a/9361542/441108 for a method that worked for me.